# Text added by jQuery does no show

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain why the string "test" does not show up when using the following HTML/jQuery?

```
<div class="month">
foo
</div>
```

JS:

```
var day_html = $('<input type="checkbox" />');
day_html.text("test");
$(".month").append(day_html);
```

[Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/pqrh5z36/1/)

Comment: Because a checkbox does not have a text attribute. Use a label

Comment: @mplungjan oh, that explains it... thanks!

Comment: PS: I did not vote this down

Answer (score -2):

What do you want to achieve ? If you want append, use append function twice.

```
var day_html = $('<input type="checkbox" />');
$(".month").append(day_html);
$(".month").append("test");
```

Comment: While that may work, it is not the right way to add a label to a checkbox because you could not click on the text for activating the checkbox. mplungjan's answer is correct, I should be using a label.